# retrieval of CouchDb get, can it be a set of documents?

Tags: database, nosql, couchdb

Everyone, i am recently reading some knowledge about Couchdb just of interest. 
It's said that it stores data as pairs of index and document. and the document is literally a structure or javascript json structure.. Compared to relational database , couchdb is much lest complex, so, it saves read/write time? right?
But i am wondering, in reality, and some websites are implemented with couchdb, but not all websites can be right to use this db.
and by the way, for retrieval of a result, just like relational db, it returns a set of data, 
Can couchdb return a set of documents. and can it return a document by a given condition?

Or it can only return a result by a given document id?

Thanx for your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Compared to relational database , couchdb is much lest complex, so, it
>   saves read/write time?

CouchDB stores individual documents in a key/value fashion which is less complex structure than RDBMS tables, but what it makes fast is it's [MVCC](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/consistency.html) model which offers high availability at expense of strong consistency.

> Can couchdb return a set of documents. and can it return a document by
>   a given condition? Or it can only return a result by a given document id?

Yes it can return document or a set of documents by a given condition through [views](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/views.html). You can also get document directly through it's ID without creating a view or fetch multiple documents through CouchDB's [HTTP bulk document API](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Bulk_Document_API).